# Do not join 2 tables but paging with them

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join, pagination

I have two oracle table:`users` and `logs`,as follow,

```
users:
---------
id   number,
name varchar2(50)

logs:
-----
user_id  number，
visit_date     date
```

I need to find out the first 10 users who never appears in the logs table (means they never visit the page),I can write a sql:

```
select * 
from users u 
where  not exists (
 select 1 from logs o 
 where o.user_id = u.id) 
and rownum<=10
```

But now the problem is these two table are not in the same schema,they could not be accessed for each other,so I can not join them.
Because there are two microservices,one microservice should query its own schema
If I fetch 10 records from `users`,maybe they all never visit the page,I need to fetch 10 more,then after that still 5 users did not visit that page,I need to fetch 5 more,and so on.So I am not sure how many record I should fetch at the first time.Is it a good idea to do so?And how to write the code?

If I fetch all the record of the 2 tables,then do join using Java code,I'm worried about the amount of data being too large.Or should I just make these two tables accessible to each other?

So,how to do paging with 2 table but not join them?

Comment: The tables don't need to be in the same schema, the user running the query just needs select privileges on both - and (in the absence of synonyms) the query needs to prefix each table with the schema it is in. If you were going to get the data from both tables independently from Java, would that be over the same connection?

Comment: @AlexPoole 2 connections, our leader told us to query one table in a microservice，then use open feign to query another table from another microservice,means a microservice should access its own schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now the problem is these two table are not in the same schema,they could not be accessed for each other,so I can not join them.

Create a user that can see both schemas and log in to that user and access the tables using `schema_name.table_name`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   schema1.users u 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   schema2.logs l
         WHERE  l.user_id = u.id
       )
ORDER BY u.something
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   schema1.users u 
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   schema2.logs l
           WHERE  l.user_id = u.id
         )
  ORDER BY u.something
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 10
```

---

Alternatively, create a third schema and `GRANT` the `SELECT` privilege on the `USERS` and `LOGS` tables in the first two schemas and then create a view in that third schema and a new micro-service and use that.

Comment: But the team rules us not use schema.table,because there are 2 microservices which should use its own schema

Comment: @vlddlv4 You should give constructive feedback to the team that the rules are preventing the development of efficient code by forcing queries to be pushed down the pipeline and not allowing you to join tables when it should be handled by a single query on the database. You can then ask the team how they should handle this because the most efficient solution is to use both schemas in the database.